# Does intensively running a gaming-laptop increase electrical costs significantly?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, power

Our electric bill has been high lately, and I was wondering if it is related to my new gaming laptop I bought. I have an MSI GT780DX. It has a huge power brick AC charging adapter, and I leave it plugged in 24/7 and am on my laptop almost all day, almost every day.

Comment: Yes it does. power is consumed mainly by CPU and GPU.

Comment: I agree it will increase the power consumption. But its still not the first thing I would look for. A small electric heater would use a lot more power then a laptop.

Comment: I added the word "significantly". You're right that it is obvious it takes electricity. What I meant, is does it take up a significant amount of electricity (enough to put a sizable increase in the monthly electrical bill), moreso than using a regular laptop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will make your total power usage go up.  But, depending on how much the change you're seeing, this might not be the only cause.

You should be able to find out what the power usage (in watts) of your laptop model via google.    Or you can just look on the AC charging adapter.  (NOTE: if it doesn't list the power, it will list current.  Something like "1.5A"  To convert from amps to watts, multiply by 120 (if in North America) or 240 (if in Europe))

Realize that the actual average wattage is likely to be less than the max unless you are running at 100%CPU usage 24 hours a day

`wattage x hours used ÷ 1000 = kWh`

`kWh x price per kWh = cost of electricity`

Let's say it's a 1.5A adapter, which is 180 watts max.  Assume it's running at an average of 90 watts for any 24 hour period  (I would think this would be **crazy** high for a laptop, but I've never used a gaming laptop...) yields  90*730/1000 = 65.7 kWh per month.

Average cost per kWh was $.112  (11.2 cents) in the USA in 2011 (see http://www.eia.gov/cneaf/electricity/epm/table5_6_a.html) but it can vary widely by location, so check your electricity bill to use an accurate number.

Note:

There are tools you can buy (such as a Kill-A-Watt) that can measure in real time the power usage of whatever they're plugged into.  You can then know *exactly* how much your laptop is using.

Comment: It's a 2.25A adapter.